# Check if Jtoken and its value exist by using Jobject.SelectToken only

Tags: c#, json, .net

is it possible to check if a certain token and value exist by providing the json path to the SelectToken method?

I have a JSON that looks like

```
{
    "id": "11111",
    "status": "succeeded",
    "values": [
        {
            "datetime": "2022-04-07T10:33:56.000Z",
            "type": "backward",
            "result": null
        },
        {
            "datetime": "2022-04-07T10:34:06.000Z",
            "type": "forward",
            "result": "accepted"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to check if a type:forward exists. I have the code:

```
 var jsonPath = "$.values[1].type";
 var jToken = obj.SelectToken(jsonPath);
```

but this only gets the value "forward" and the index (1) is not always defined and must not be hard-coded. I have deserialized this and performed Linq but I would like to know if there are other possible solutions by just providing the path to the SelectToken method?

Answer (score 0):

I already found the answer. I just used this path

```
var jsonPath = "$.values[?(@type == 'forward')]";
```